# Getting error while running the selenium test cases with selenium grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

My browser invocation code is like:

```
else if(browserName.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/selenium-drivers/chromedriver");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
            URL url_hub = new URL("http://my-remote-server-ip:4444/wd/hub");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url_hub, capabilities);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
        }
```

Getting the following error while running the program :

> Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
>   [[image: grid -console]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuUke.png)

Comment: Did you start the HUB & NODE with success?

Comment: @Dev yes .And I have got the console message "08:40:54.801 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
"

Comment: Can you show me the commands how you started Hub & Node? Thanks

Comment: @Dev I am running the hub through Jenkins and the command I am using for node "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://my-server-ip:4444/grid/register
"

Comment: check the grid console if you see the node registered

Comment: @metar I have attached the grid console screenshot.Please check and let men know what else information I need to provide .

Comment: remove capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS); in your code and its fixed. you run the node on linux but you query the hub for a windows node

Comment: @metar I have changed that in code ,now its working fine when I am running the program in local machine but still getting the same error while running the code on cloud.

Comment: @Sidhartha you see chrome popping up on your local machine? If he uses a remote node you can easily see that in the grid - the icon is greyed out than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer of your Question:

### Windows Platform

1. Start the Selenium Grid Hub. Confirm the log message:

   ```
   14:25:50.350 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
   ```
2. Open grid console URL (in my case http://localhost:4444/grid/console) and observe the console.
3. Start the Selenium Grid Node & register it to the Hub:

   ```
   java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe -jar C:\Utility\selenium-server-standalone\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
   ```
4. Look out for the Node Registration Logs:

   ```
   14:33:12.354 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
   14:33:12.409 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
   14:33:12.409 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
   14:33:12.756 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
   ```
5. Here is own working set of code twisted a bit to fit into my local Windows 8 box as `localhost:4444` settings:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
   DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
   cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
   URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
   WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, cap);
   driver.get("http://google.com/");
   System.out.println("Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
   driver.quit();
   ```
6. I get a result as:

   ```
   Title is : Google
   PASSED: test1

   ===============================================
   Default test
   Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
   ===============================================
   ```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I have followed all the above steps but getting "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'arima-latitude-3460', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-117-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
" this error.

Comment: Your OS is Linux, so you have to make certain changes accordingly. 1.Path of `chromedriver` (linux type absolute path & without extension). 2. Change `Platform.WINDOWS` to `Platform.LINUX` 3. Pass exact IP & port instead of `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: I have changed that in code ,now its working fine when I am running the program in local machine but still getting the same error while running the code on cloud.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144551/discussion-between-sidhartha-and-dev).