# Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed connecting Selenium Grid Node to Grid Hub

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm facing an error connecting Selenium Grid Node to Selenium Grid Hub.

Selenium Node command output:

```
C:\Users\FTXSservice\Downloads>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.30.1:4444/grid/register -port 5566
09:23:26.072 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
09:23:26.150 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 5566
2020-08-06 09:23:26.337:INFO::main: Logging initialized @411ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
09:23:26.525 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
09:23:26.604 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 5566
09:23:26.604 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
09:23:26.666 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
09:23:48.057 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.Failed to connect to /192.168.30.1:4444
09:23:48.072 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.30.1:4444/grid/register
09:24:09.150 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect to /192.168.30.1:4444
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the quotes i.e. `"..."` around the *absolute path* of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) and you can use the following command:

```
C:\Users\FTXSservice\Downloads>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.30.1:4444/grid/register -port 5566
```

Ideally, you need to put the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) binaries within a directory, as an example `C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe`

Additionally, ensure that:

1. [Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647961/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-selenium-grid/59648301#59648301) Hub and [Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496191/selenium-grid-listening-on-node-port-instead-of-hub-port/46524276#46524276) Node versions are identical.
2. [Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041276/getting-error-while-running-the-selenium-test-cases-with-selenium-grid/44043640#44043640) Hub is up and running.

Comment: Hi Debajan i have tried the following command but i get the error message  same as before

Comment: unable to parse the url: http://192.168.30.1.4444:-1/grid/api/proxy?id=http://10.152.38.250:5555 what this means @DebanjanB

Comment: @gt7233 Where did you find it?

Comment: @gt7233 Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: C:\Users\FTXSservice\Downloads>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.30.1:4444/grid/register -port 5566
10:34:02.059 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.Failed to connect to /192.168.30.1:4444
10:34:02.059 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.30.1:4444/grid/register @DebanjanB

Comment: now i am getting the following error and the previous error unable to parse the URl ii got that error when i tried on a different laptop (which is used for node)