# What is a hub in the Selenium grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium3

As per the documentation:

> Hub is the central point in the Selenium Grid that routes the JSON test commands to the nodes. It receives test requests from the client and routes them to the required nodes.

What is a hub in the Selenium grid?

Answer (score 0):

### [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/)

[Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647961/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-selenium-grid/59648301#59648301) allows the execution of WebDriver scripts on remote machines (virtual or real) by routing commands sent by the client to remote browser instances. It aims to provide an easy way to run tests in parallel on multiple machines.

[image: Selenium Grid]

In simple words, [Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496191/selenium-grid-listening-on-node-port-instead-of-hub-port/46524276#46524276) allows us to run tests in parallel on multiple machines, and to manage different browser versions and browser configurations centrally (instead of in each individual test).

---

### [Selenium Grid Hub](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/grid_3/components_of_a_grid/#hub)

The [Selenium Grid Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041276/getting-error-while-running-the-selenium-test-cases-with-selenium-grid/44043640#44043640) is the central point where all your tests are sent. Each Selenium Grid consists of exactly one hub. The hub needs to be reachable from the respective clients (i.e. CI server, Developer machine etc.) The hub will connect one or more nodes that tests will be delegated to.